# VueJS Route Component clearing recursive setTimeout() on route change

Tags: vue.js, recursion, settimeout, livechat, cleartimeout

I am building a messaging application with live refresh using VueJS front-end and PHP backend.
I am using setTimeout() to pull new messages from the back-end like so:-

```
    var Conversation = Vue.component('conversation',{
        data: function(){
          return {
            refresh_timer: null,
            messages: [],
            conversation_id: window.CONVERSATION_ID,
            route: window.ROUTE
          }
        },
        created : function(){
           // Starting the recursive call
           this.loadNewMessages();
        },
        destroyed () {
          clearTimeout(this.refresh_timer);
        },
        methods: {
          loadNewMessages(){
            let lastMessage = this.messages[this.messages.length - 1];
            axios.get(this.route, {
              params: {
                conversation_id: this.conversation_id,
                last_message: lastMessage.id
              }
            }).then(res => {
              if (res.status == 200){
                this.messages.push(...res.data.messages);

                setTimeout(this.loadNewMessages, 5000);
              }
            }).catch(error => console.log(error));
                  }
        },
        beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
          // Refreshing the timer
          clearTimeout(this.refresh_timer);
          next();
        }
    }
```

I am also using ":key" on the router view to update the component completely when the route is changed.

```
<router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
```

This all works fine. When a conversation is opened, new messages are pulled frequently, every 5 seconds a request is sent to the server and new messages are pulled.

But the problem is when user switches a conversation using "router-link", the Conversation component on the router view is refreshed and the new conversation comes to the view. It also starts pulling messages for the new conversation.

But the "created" method for the new conversation component is triggered and "this.loadNewMessages()" is called once again. Which starts another recursive pulling.

Now I have two setTimeout() functions calling themselves every 5 seconds. Whenever a conversation is changed, a new setTimeout() is started.

If a user changes conversation 10 times in a page, 10 different recursive setTimeout() starts and runs on the page. The clearTimeout() inside the "destroyed" or "beforeRouteUpdate" doesn't seem to work. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are never saving the token returned by `setInterval`.

This should fix it:

```
if (res.status == 200){
   this.messages.push(...res.data.messages);

   this.refresh_timer = setTimeout(this.loadNewMessages, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I did that actually. But it isn't working either.